# How to change size of the running app window at beginning R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am running a shiny app by clicking run in window in the left menu. However this window came up too narrowed it only included my sidebarpanel width which is 2 inches. How to change this window size and make it bigger width and height? Thank you.

Question was asked before but left unaswered.

[Change size of RStudio Window on start of Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491673/change-size-of-rstudio-window-on-start-of-shiny-app)

Comment: Partly answered here for the maximize window case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371164/how-to-run-r-shiny-app-in-full-sized-window

Comment: It is for the browser case as I understand. But I asked for the run in window case. I could run it fullscreen in chrome browser. No problem. Or else I choose the forth option informing user.