# Set specific window size for RStudio shiny app on all screen types

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm trying to set a specific window size for a shiny app. The app will only be run in RStudio, and not in a browser.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491673/change-size-of-rstudio-window-on-start-of-shiny-app) suggests to use a `runGadget` call, in place of `shinyApp(ui, server)` at the end of `app.R` - for example:

```
runGadget(ui, server, viewer = dialogViewer("Window Title",
                                            width = 1200, height = 700))
```

But, I get different results depending on whether the screen is internal (i.e. laptop) or external (i.e. a separate monitor).

For example, on a **1280 x 800** non-retina MacBook screen, the above settings only give **1083 x 558**, despite there apparently being enough space for a **1200 x 700** window.

And, on a **2560 x 1600** retina MacBook screen, the window size is **2166 x 1098** – a similar proportion of the screen as for the non-retina MacBook.

However, on an external **1680 x 1050** monitor, I get exactly **1200 x 700**, as specified.

Is there a way to force an exact window size across all situations? I would also prefer the window style output by `shinyApp(ui, server)`, rather than an RStudio dialog if possible.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I ran into the same problem